# Using cmake to build Matlab mex file with C and Fortran functions compiled on Windows

Tags: matlab, windows-7, cmake, mex, gfortran

Using Windows 7, with Matlab R2011a (32-bit), I would like to use Cmake to compile a Matlab mex file (`procedure.c`) written in C.  This file contains the `void mexFunction()` required for interfacing with Matlab.  However, the C code within this file calls a subroutine written in Fortran 95 (found in file `fp.F`).

At least, there are two files that need to be compiled:

```
procedure.c
fp.F
```

In the future, I will have to eventually compile and link together other C code files and Fortran functions.

I would like to do this using the Windows platform, with `gcc` or `Visual Studio 2010` as the C compiler and `gfortran` as the Fortran compiler.

Must I use only the supported Matlab compilers?

It appears that `Open Watcom` can create object files suitable for mex, but I can't use `Open Watcom` since it only supports `f77`.  The code that I have in Fortran was written for a gcc compiler running on a UNIX OS.

There appears to be un-official support for object files created using Open Watcom:
http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-155BQG/?solution=1-155BQG

---

The issue is linking all of this together with Cmake, gcc or Visual Studio, and gfortran.  Perhaps Cmake is not optimal, and another type of scripting language could be used?

I do not have access to Intel Visual Fortran on Windows.